# Tools for monitoring electron applications

Tags: node.js, performance, electron, monitoring

We are building an electron app using React & NodeJS.
I was wondering what are the preferred app monitoring tools out there that provide good support for monitoring these sort of apps (Web running on desktop) and adhere to the desktop app rules.

For the web, we have many tools like Keymetrics, dynatrace, etc but I guess they are all very web-specific (one server, etc). I am looking for something that fulfills the desktop use case where the app will be running on millions of computers and it gives me insights into how the app is performing on the majority of systems.
Specifically, I am looking for things like:

1 - Distributed IPC tracing
2 - P9x metrics
3 - Env info => Os, network
4 - Filesystem metrics
etc.

I looked into Sentry & NewRelic, but I want to gather your feedback from potential experiences of these tools.

Any suggestion or leads are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you already use Dynatrace I would suggest to have a closer look at [Dynatrace Openkit](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/openkit/). It's maybe not exactly what you are searching for. But I used it successfully to monitor a Java-based rich client application and there seems to be also a JS-version of it available [here](https://github.com/Dynatrace/openkit-js). The focus of the library is more on user experience but you can easily track things like OS, screen width, product version, user ID and location (autom. detected from IP address). With actions you can track any kind of operation and add optional key value pairs.

I'm not sure what you exactly mean with distributed IPC tracing. With the libray you can at least track outgoing web requests. You can also add a header to web requests so that they can be correlated with transactions of a remote backend that is already monitored with Dynatrace.

The library does neither provide any network / disk montoring by default nor metrics. For the first you could add properties or events to an action. For the later you could maybe use  the [metrics API](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/metric-v2/). I used properties on actions to track additional data like the size of a loaded document but I haven't used the metrics API yet. To my understanding the metrics should be chartable (incl. percentiles) like any other metric in Dynatrace.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io/) to monitor an electron js application. Please check the docs [here](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual).